# Using specific column values in non-select clauses in SQLAlchemy 2.0/Mapped Classes ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I tried to do the following in SQLAlchemy 2.0 using a [MappedClass](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html):

```
async with sessionmanager.session() as db_session:
    await db_session.execute(update(MyMappedClass).values(slug=slugify(MyMappedClass.c.title)))
```

(Ignore the fact that this is async, 99% sure it's immaterial.)

The part that didn't work as `MyMappedClass.c.title` which (I gleaned from the error) returned a `Comparator` object rather than a string. I thought this would work because it looks like this syntax works with SQLAlchemy tables ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_update.html#the-update-sql-expression-construct)). Is there some way to do a similar thing with mapped classes? Please let me know if I got something else wrong.

Comment: `table_obj.c.column_name` is used with SQLAlchemy Core `Table` objects. To refer to a column (attribute) in an ORM object just use `MyMappedClass.title`.

Comment: That syntax didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A values call like `.values(slug=<some_expression>)` only works if `<some_expression>` is either pure Python, like `'a' + 'b'` or `1 + 2`, or can be converted by SQLAlchemy into an SQL expression. For example, in the example in the docs
`"Username: " + user_table.c.name` can be converted to `'Username: ' || name` at the SQL level, because SQLAlchemy maps the `+` operator for string data types to `||`.

However `slugify(MyMappedClass.title)` cannot be mapped in this way, because SQLAlchemy doesn't know how to map `slugify` to an SQL expression.

You could possibly provide an expression yourself. If `slugify` was defined like this:

```py
def slugify(s):
    return s.lower().replace(' ', '-')
```

then your update statement would be

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
...
update(MyMappedClass).values(slug=func.replace(func.lower(MyMappedClass.title), ' ', '-'))
```

If `slugify` is not expressible in this way then you would need to retrieve the rows for update and call `slugify` in the Python layer:

```py
from sqlalchemy import bindparam,select, update
...
with Session.begin() as s:
    mms = s.scalars(select(MyMappedClass))
    values = [{'id': mm.id, 'slug': slugify(mm.title)} for mm in mms]
    stmt = update(MyMappedClass).values(slug=bindparam('slug'))
    s.execute(stmt, values)
```